# Javascript not executing on elements after ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a table with some images, when the Ajax is called it removes the previous table and returns another table with new images.

```
$("img").click(function(){
    $.post("gallery.php", function(data){
        $("#left-gallery, #right-gallery").html("").append(data);
    });
});
```

This is how I get the information from the php file.

The problem is that the new elements does not trigger the click events that the previous ones use to.

If I clicked on an image in the table it should replace another image on the page outside the table.

```
$("#left-gallery img").click(function(){
    $("#left-gallery td").removeClass("highlighted");

    var source = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#image1-image").attr("src", source); //replaces a big image outside the table
    $(this).parents("td").addClass("highlighted");
});
```

The table images are nested like :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a  href = "image.jpg"> 
            <img src = "image.jpg">
            Image
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Even preventing the  default behaviour does not work.

```
$("td a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The javascript is after the `<body>` and is internal. I do not know how to get the click events or any to work on the returned table and any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: @undefined OK guys from now on let's close duplicated questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use delegation because you are dynamically modifying the DOM

```
$('#left-gallery').on('click','img',function(){
        // your code here
})
```

By doing this, you attach the event handler to the #left-gallery element = which is static.  It will then listen for click events from descendant images and handle them as they bubble up

Depending on which version of jQuery you are using

> $('element').live('event',function({ code here..}));                // jQuery 1.3+
>
> $('staticparent').delegate('element', 'event', function(){ code here..});  // jQuery 1.4.3+
>
> $('staticparent').on('event', 'element', function(){ code here.. });        // jQuery 1.7+

You were doing

```
$("#left-gallery img").click(function(){
```

Which binds the event handlers to the images..  The images no longer exist after you modified the dom.. and you never binding event handlers to the newly added images so thats why the clicking didn't do anything

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. However I still have problems preventing the default behaviour of the anchor tag. I tried  
`$("td").on("click","a",function(e){` .

Comment: @Fee Just do what you did in your post above.. pass in event or e and do a e.preventDefault()

Comment: Everything works find now. I understand delegation now, thanks again

Comment: @Fee Your welcome.. Glad this helped you understand delegation :)

Comment: +1 (actually we should close duplicates... however...keep that in mind) Ah, and thanks for my point